# Animation causes AsyncTask HttpClient task to be super slow

Tags: android

I have a network task defined inside of an AsyncTask that takes approximately 2-3 seconds to complete.

When I add the animation code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:duration="60"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" />
```

and then in my activity execute it as follows:

```
progressImageView = (ImageView) getWindow().findViewById(
            R.id.progressImageView);
progressAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.progress);
progressImageView.startAnimation(progressAnimation);
```

The network call takes approximately 12-13 seconds to complete. Am I doing something incredibly wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess the problem is the duration value, it is specified in milliseconds, I'm guessing you intended it to be more like 6000 or 60000 (1 min).

A value that small is probably causing the UI thread to get backed up with a large number of frame updates that delay it from processing the the onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute code in the Async task.

Try setting the duration to a larger value.

Comment: It seems like this was the issue. Thanks.